# Handle MEDIA_BUTTON not working when start bluetoothSCO

Tags: android, bluetooth, record

I'm implement an audio recorder with bluetooth speaker. The bluetooth speaker have some media button such as play/pause, next, previous. I trigger play button to record and press again to stop. But the problem is when using mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco() to using bluetooth microphone to record, the Media_button receiver is not working anymore, can't receive any event.

Below is the sourcecode: 
Register receiver:

```
    ((AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE)).registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(
            new ComponentName(
                    this,
                    MediaButtonReceiver.class.getName()));
```

MediaButtonReceiver:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("MediaButtonReceiver", "onReceive Media button!" );
        KeyEvent key = (KeyEvent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        Log.d("MediaButtonReceiver", "Media button! action: [" + key.getAction() + "] key code: [" + key.getKeyCode() + "]");
        if(key.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            int action = fromKeyCodeToAction(key.getKeyCode());
            switch (action) {
                case ACTION_START_STOP_TALKING:
                    LogUtils.LOGD("MediaButtonReceiver", "Action start/stop");
                    startStopRecord();
                    break;
```

... I handle some logic in hear to check current status record or not. and trigger the service to start or stop record. And this is code for start record.

```
if (isBluetoothHeadsetConnected) {
                LogUtils.LOGI("Bluetooth", "record using headset");
                //we just start recording when the audio state is connected
                mContext.registerReceiver(mBluetoothAudioStateBroadcastReceiver, mBluetoothAudioStateIntentFilter);
                LogUtils.LOGI("Bluetooth", "startBluetoothSco");
                mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
                mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
            } else {
                LogUtils.LOGI("Bluetooth", "record normally ");
                mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
                mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
                handleStartRecordJob();
            }
```

If I remove startBluetoothSco(), the receiver work normal, but app using device mic instead of bluetooth speaker. If I don't remove, receiver is not working anymore and I can't stop the recorder. 
Do you have any solution to work arround?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? can you please shed some light if you have.

Comment: Often the media button will actually be programmed to hangup a sco connection when one is active. You can register the handler to listen for SCO hangup to control the media button in this case.

Comment: I had the same problem. I tested my app with several Handsfree devices. With one of them the media control events was received, with others - no. So, for my opinion, it's hardware problem some of handsfree systems. See more information about interaction during Bluetooth SCO mode here: http://gopinaths.gitlab.io/post/bluetooth_sco_android/

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Media Button listener with Microphone module. I guess in deep down it uses MediaSession same as Microphone( it uses android.telecom)